# JSON bs-datepicker object different from selected

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, date, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

So these dates have been doing my head in.  I have a MVC4/angularjs application with bs-datepicker.  It was submitting fine but recently it was highlighted that the dates are all over the place.  Users would be selecting the 4th of July and on submit it saves as 3rd of July.

I placed the object in an expression and it was browser specific.

```
<input bs-datepicker  data-date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" class="form-control" ng-model="data.FirstDay" type="text" required>
```

In Chrome when you select 04/07/2015, the object value is "2015-07-04T01:00:00.000Z"

In Firefox when you select 04/07/2015, the object value is "2015-07-03T13:00:00.000Z"

In Internet Explorer when you select 04/07/2015, the object value is "2015-07-03T13:00:00.000Z"

Is there anyone can I just force it to the selected date?

Comment: I think the problem is with your server date setup/configuration like the timezone. You need to configure it properly.

Comment: Thanks, considered that but it doesn't make sense that in chrome there isn't a time zone but in FF and IE there is?  I just want to strip out the timezone and make it so whatever date you pick is the date that the date object has.